# Change weather icon with WeatherKit (SwiftUI)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, weatherkit

Very new to SwiftUI.
I'm working on a very simple weather app using Apple's WeatherKit.
Have no problem getting the temperature and other parameters but I'd like to change the systemImage icon (sun, cloud, moon, etc...) to a corresponding emoji.
Tried to create an enum with no luck:

```
import Foundation
import WeatherKit
import SwiftUI

@MainActor class WeatherKitManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var weather: Weather?
    
    
    func getWeather() async {
        do {
            weather = try await Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
                return try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: .init(latitude: 42.28851, longitude: 13.55401))  // Coordinates for SAN PIO just as example coordinates
            }.value
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
    
    enum WeatherEmoji: String, Codable {
        case blowingDust = "blowingDust"
        case clear = "clear"
        case cloudy = "cloudy"
        case foggy = "foggy"
        case haze = "haze"
        case mostlyClear = "mostlyClear"
        case mostlyCloudy = "mostlyCloudy"
        case partlyCloudy = "partlyCloudy"
        case smokey = "smokey"
        case breezy = "breezy"
        case windy = "windy"
        case drizzle = "drizzle"
        case heavyRain = "heavyRain"
        case isolatedThunderstorms = "isolatedThunderstorms"
        case rain = "rain"
        case sunShowers = "sunShowers"
        case scatteredThunderstorms = "scatteredThunderstorms"
        case strongStorms = "strongStorms"
        case thunderstorms = "thunderstorms"
        case frigid = "frigid"
        case hail = "hail"
        case hot = "hot"
        case flurries = "flurries"
        case sleet = "sleet"
        case snow = "snow"
        case sunFlurries = "sunFlurries"
        case wintryMix = "wintryMix"
        case blizzard = "blizzard"
        case blowingSnow  = "blowingSnow"
        case freezingDrizzle = "freezingDrizzle"
        case freezingRain = "freezingRain"
        case heavySnow = "heavySnow"
        case hurricane = "hurricane"
        case tropicalStorm = "tropicalStorm"
        
        var emojiweather: LocalizedStringKey {
            
            switch self {
            case .clear:
                return "☀️"
            case .blowingDust:
                return ""
            case .cloudy:
                return "☁️"
            case .foggy:
                return "️"
            case .haze:
                return "‍️"
            case .mostlyClear:
                return "️"
            case .mostlyCloudy:
                return "️"
            case .partlyCloudy:
                return "⛅️"
            case .smokey:
                return "‍️"
            case .breezy:
                return ""
            case .windy:
                return ""
            case .drizzle:
                return "☔️"
            case .heavyRain:
                return "️"
            case .isolatedThunderstorms:
                return "⚡️"
            case .rain:
                return "️"
            case .sunShowers:
                return "️"
            case .scatteredThunderstorms:
                return "⚡️"
            case .strongStorms:
                return "⛈️"
            case .thunderstorms:
                return "⛈️"
            case .frigid:
                return ""
            case .hail:
                return "❄️"
            case .hot:
                return ""
            case .flurries:
                return ""
            case .sleet:
                return "️"
            case .snow:
                return "☃️"
            case .sunFlurries:
                return "️"
            case .wintryMix:
                return ""
            case .blizzard:
                return "️"
            case .blowingSnow:
                return "️"
            case .freezingDrizzle:
                return ""
            case .freezingRain:
                return "️"
            case .heavySnow:
                return "️"
            case .hurricane:
                return "️"
            case .tropicalStorm:
                return "️"
            }
        }
    }
    
    var lookslikemoji: String {
        let myemoji = "\(WeatherEmoji.self)"
        return "\(myemoji)"
    }
    
    var symbol: String {
        weather?.currentWeather.symbolName ?? "xmark"
    }
    
    var temp: String {
        let temp = weather?.currentWeather.temperature
        
        let convert = temp?.converted(to: .celsius).formatted(.measurement(width: .narrow, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0))))
        return convert ?? "Loading Weather Data"
        
    }
    
    var feelslike: String {
        
        let feelslike = weather?.currentWeather.apparentTemperature
        
        let convert = feelslike?.converted(to: .celsius).formatted(.measurement(width: .narrow, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0))))
        return convert ?? "Loading Weather Data"
        
     } 
 }
```

What am I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to convert the `WeatherCondition` enum case which matches the `symbol` property

1. Declare an extension of `WeatherCondition` with a computed property  `emoji`

   ```
   extension WeatherCondition {
       var emoji : String {
           switch self {

           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The compiler will show a `Switch must be exhaustive` error. Click on the little red circle and then on `Fix`. This adds stubs for all cases.
3. Return the corresponding emoji for each case for example

   ```
   case .blizzard: return "️"
   case .blowingDust: return ""
   ...
   ```
4. In the view show the emoji with  `weather.condition.emoji`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Extensions are so powerful! Learned a lot! Thank you!